# Hamburger button in WebView of Android studio does not work

Tags: android

I have a problem in clicking on hamburger button, which was contained in website, website is also called by WebView, like `webView.loadUrl(query)`

but hamburger button contained in website does not work at all.

Thank you for your help and have a nice day.

as well as that, I also set

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        if(webView.canGoBack()){
            webView.goBack();
            return false;
        }
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}

private class HybridWebViewClient extends WebViewClient{
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if(view != null) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: If the hamburger button requires javascript, you'll have to enable javascript within the web settings - http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html

Comment: Did you enabled javascript for the webview?